# For-loop ignores delay(300)

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have the following loop that's supposed to add a class for EACH elements in `formInputs`, wait 300 ms, then remove it again as many times as defined in `flashCount`. So in this case 2 times.

But for some reason the `delay(300)` is not working and my loop is going super fast that I don't even see the visual effects of it.

How can I fix this?

```
for (var key in formInputs) {
    if (formInputs.hasOwnProperty(key) && !formInputs[key]["input"].val()) {
        var flashCount = 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < flashCount; i++) {
            formInputs[key]["input"].addClass("hovered").delay(300).removeClass("hovered");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without the for loop, do you get the expected action (just once)?

Comment: Please read the documentation carefully on what `.delay` does.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is jQuery only uses `delay` in its internal animation queue. Since `addClass` and `removeClass` aren't animations, you have to add them to the queue yourself. Like so:

```
for (var key in formInputs) {
    if (formInputs.hasOwnProperty(key) && !formInputs[key]["input"].val()) {
        var flashCount = 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < flashCount; i++) {
            // Add the function to jQuery's animation queue instead of removing the class straight away
            formInputs[key]["input"].addClass("hovered").delay(300).queue(function(next){
                // Remove the `hovered` class when the queue gets to this
                $(this).removeClass("hovered");
                // Call the next item in the queue
                next();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I can't test this, but should work.

Comment: This only gets executed once, though.

Comment: Can you post anything more - maybe as a JSFiddle? Would help to see exactly what your problem is.

Comment: I believe he wants to pause the loop entirely like in other languages.